# Invalid Credentials using Google Cloud Platform Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

We have a bucket in Google Cloud Platform to manage pictures.
I am trying to upload a picture to it using Curl.

Respective to the official documentation linked [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-csharp), this is the Curl-command I used:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @cat.jpeg \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer A_STRING_SUPPOSED_TO_BE_A_KEY" \
    -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/upload_zone/o?uploadType=media&name=cat"
```

This is the answer we get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems our key is invalid, we are not sure what to use as Authorization key. Where can we find the OAUTH2.0-key required to make use of the Google Cloud Platform Bucket, do we need to generate it somewhere?

**Edit:**
We have generated a key using the OAuth 2.0-Playground, and it worked! But the key expires every 3000 seconds...

Comment: Using `curl` is a developer solution and not a good long-term solution. Write code that uses a service account JSON key file to authorize requests. Google Cloud Storage requires OAuth tokens. The maximum lifetime of a token is 3,600 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already authenticated to Google using the gcloud sdk, you can get the key like this:

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
```

So, using your example above, this should work:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @cat.jpeg \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
"https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/upload_zone/o?uploadType=media&name=cat"
```

Comment: And if I'm not logged in? Can't I just copy it as an API-key?

Comment: If you just copy it, the key will expire. It depends on how long you need the key for.

Comment: Okay, thanks mate. Can you give me a reference on how to login to Google Cloud Platform using cURL/HTTP Request? Thx mate.

Comment: The only ways I handle is to either have my session gcloud auth'ed using a service key (or service key impersonation) and then use curl as above, or, use a python script to make the authenticated API calls, eliminating curl altogether. Ultimately though, you still need to authenticate first.  Here is a primer on API handling for the later: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses